# Cannot share to Facebook messenger from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-messenger

I am trying to share some text from my game to Facebook messenger.

Using the latest Facebook iOS SDK (4.33), and copying the example found in Facebook's documentation, I am getting the following error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb-messenger-share-api:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I have added "fb-messenger-share-api" to the "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" in info.plist. If I understand correctly, this error means that the application is not installed. BUT, it is installed...

Here is the code I am using (which is actually just copied from the sample):

```
FBSDKShareMessengerURLActionButton *urlButton = [[FBSDKShareMessengerURLActionButton alloc] init];
urlButton.title = @"Visit Facebook";
urlButton.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"];

FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateElement *element = [[FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateElement alloc] init];
element.title = @"This is a Cat Picture";
element.subtitle = @"Look at this cat, wow! Amazing.";
element.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg"];
element.button = urlButton;

FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateContent *content = [[FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateContent alloc] init];
content.pageID = "1";// Your page ID, required for attribution
content.element = element;

FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
messageDialog.shareContent = content;

if ([messageDialog canShow]) {
    [messageDialog show];
}
```

The canShow method calls canOpenURL with the proper url scheme, which creates the error.

Any ideas what might be wrong here? The documentation is pretty lame...

Comment: HeyRan, did you ever figure this out?  I am having some of the same issues you describe... and yes, the doc is very lame!!!

Comment: As much as I remember, I figured facebook had to update their Unity SDK to include the messenger API. Haven't tried it again yet, so I am not sure about the latest version. Sorry